# How would you unit-test or perform the most effective automated testing on graphics code for OpenGL?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, graphics, opengl, test-automation

I'm writing a game and the accompanying graphics engine on top of OpenGL in C++. Im also a fan of good coding processes and automated testing. Graphics code + testing seems pretty immiscible, since the output is often visual only, or very heavily visual-oriented.

For example, imagine analyzing the raw image-stream that is rendered to the screen byte-by-byte - you need test-data to compare with, which is hard to create/obtain, and often the rendered images aren't identical on a byte level when running at different times - small changes in algorithms will wreck this approach completely.

I'm thinking of creating a visual unit-test suite, in which I can basically render different test-scenes, showing stuff like shadow mapping, animation, etc etc etc. As part of CI, these scenes would then be rendered to a video file (or possibly leave it as a executable) with different metrics. This would still require manual inspection of the video file, but atleast it would be somewhat automated and standardised.

What do you think? I'm hoping there are better ways?

Comment: This is a good question, I'm wondering if you'd get better answers at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ since there might be more people there who have dealt with this before.

Comment: Since you use OpenGL, consider studying the way how Khronos group performs [conformance testing](http://www.khronos.org/conformance/ "more info here") for this API. Colleagues in my ex-project who dealt with it told me that Khronos graphics testing is as close to perfect as it gets

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Thanks, I *completely* forgot about gamedev.stackexchange... I searched programmers pretty thoroughly, but not that one. It seems most of the answers on unit testing over there focuses on the usually tested stuff though, so maybe this isn't a duplicate. Will check some more though, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

The opencv image processing library does it by saving the image and comparing it to a reference image - it has a bunch of [c++ test functions and macros](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/QA_in_OpenCV) to handle approximate image matching etc.

Comment: I'll try to check it out more in depth myself, but that page doesn't say anything about the approximate image matching. Do you know if it would work for regression testing in the case of comparing frames? Then I could visually inspect the first time a scene is rendered, note it as a reference so on. Does OpenCV have ready functions for this I could use? :p

Comment: @max generally there is a 'gold' version of the test function that generates the reference  frame and is run once when creating the test. In the distribution there is are a few "test image compare" macros. I don't think there is anything specific to read back openGL buffers to an image but that's easy enough

Answer (score 4):

Your test framework can render its test image into a buffer, retrieve the rendered image, and compare it to a "golden" reference image which has been previously generated for that purpose.

This will not work as well for cases in which the results of your test are not expected to remain *exactly* the same.  However, you can compute the squared difference of the test and reference images, and compare it against a threshold.

You may also want to provide for logging and checking performance data, since a major regression in performance is another possible failure mode.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you can't compare the output images, at least you'll be able to test that your renders complete appropriately (no crashes, long waits, etc, etc). Finding a way to check the images is better, of course, but even without it you'll have gained something from the tests.

Comment: Exactly: I was about to answer something similar ("Even if you have a unit test that just blindly generates the video file and does some trivial tests (e.g. has the right length, not completely black, not completely white), it might be enough to catch many regression errors. Especially those which simply cause your functions to throw an exception.") but there is no need for a second similar answer, so I leave it just as a comment here.